# Threadlocal on tomcat misbehaviour after upgrading to JAVA 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, thread-local

I use thread local to store a user request specific features (ex. browser agent) it used to work fine on JAVA 7, but now after upgrading to JAVA 8 In some cases I see requests coming from android browser handled as if its coming from iOS browser even though it was detected correctly as android browser but later on while processing the request it was replaced with another thread local value! am not sure what am missing here can anyone help me? my environment setup (before/after) upgrade is:

- tomcat 8 before and after.
- JAVA upgraded from 7 to 8.
- Spring upgraded from 4.1.7 to 4.2.5
- Spring security upgraded from 3.2.3 to 4.03

I have a security filter that looks something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
private final IdentityService identityService;

public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(IdentityService userService) {
    this.identityService = userService;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityManager.manager().clearManager();
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);
    String agent = httpRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");
    SecurityManager.manager().setAgent(agent);

    ...

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

And the Security manager looks like this:

```
import com.appseleon.platform.web.shared.CrossAppConstants;

public class SecurityManager {
private static SecurityManager manager;

private final ThreadLocal<String> agentContext = new ThreadLocal<String>();

private SecurityManager() {
    manager = this;
}

public void clearManager() {
    agentContext.set(null);
}

public static SecurityManager manager() {
    return manager;
}


public String getAgent() {
    String os = agentContext.get();
    if (os == null) {
        os = CrossAppConstants.DEFAULT_OS;
    }
    return os;
}

public void setAgent(String agent) {
    System.out.println("### os detected: " + agent);
    agentContext.set(agent);
}

}
```

Finally after setting the agent and in various areas of my code I call the SecurityManager to get the current user agent:

```
SecurityManager.manager().getAgent()
```

Can anyone help me figure out the cause of this issue, or even an alternative more reliable way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters your `SecurityManager` is flawed you should not get an instance but simply directly get/set the value on the `ThreadLocal` using `static`. Currently you might run into issues when things get loaded in a different class loader i.e. doesn't detect the singleton.

```
public abstract class SecurityManager {

  private static final ThreadLocal<String> agentContext = new ThreadLocal<String>();

  private SecurityManager() { }

  public static void clearManager() {
      agentContext.set(null);
  }


  public static String getAgent() {
      String os = agentContext.get();
      if (os == null) {
          os = CrossAppConstants.DEFAULT_OS;
      }
      return os;
  }

  public static void setAgent(String agent) {
      System.out.println("### os detected: " + agent);
      agentContext.set(agent);
  }

}
```

Then directly call the get/set methods on this.

In your filter you should wrap the `filterChain.doFilter` in a `try / finally` block in the `finally` always clear the thread local.

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} finally {
    SecurityManager.clearManager();
}
```

Also instead of extending `GenericFilterBean` you might want to extend `OncePerRequestFilter` which makes sure this functionality is only called once (especially useful if you have some forwards in your logic) and it works only for `HttpServletRequest` type of requests, saves you some code.

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse ress, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String agent = req.getHeader("User-Agent");
        SecurityManager.setAgent(agent);

        ...
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            SecurityManager.clearManager();
        }
    }
}
```

This is also the way Spring Security works and Springs Transaction management for instance (with the static methods and shared `ThreadLocal`).

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it and post the result back!

Comment: I took my time to test and monitor it properly and this solution works fine :)
thanks!

Comment: How to verify it?